# Show $0$ is the only cluster point of the set $A = ${$\frac{1}{n} : n\in\mathbb N$}

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Need a check of working, I'm new to cluster points.

Define $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Clearly $A =$ {$\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb N$} $=$ {$(a_n)$}. Now $a_n$ converges to $0$, thus every subsequence of $a_n$ also converges to $0$. Hence $0$ is the only cluster point of the set A.

Does that suffice, or is there something to add?

Comment: Whether or not your argument is correct depends on what you know about cluster points. What is the definition? Is the definition given in terms of sequences?

Comment: The definition I've become familiar with; Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$ and let $x_0 \in \mathbb R$, $x_0$ is a cluster point pf $A$ if for all $\epsilon > 0$ the set $(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon) \cap A\setminus${$x_0$} $\ne$ the empty set.

Comment: I've also come familiar with the synonymity of $x_0 $ is a cluster point AND there exists a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $A\setminus${$x_0$} such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n = x_0$

Comment: Moreover I use the fact that if a sequence converges to say $L$, then every subsequence (of that sequence) must also converge to $L$

Comment: How are you defining "cluster point"? Typical definition: a point $x$ is a cluster point of $A$ if every open neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ **other than** $x$ **itself**, So, the fact that a sequence of points in $A$ converges to $x$ doesn't automatically make $x$ a cluster point (consider the constant sequence $a_n = x$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument shows that $0$ is a cluster point, since $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $A\setminus \{0\}$ that converges to $A$. However, it doesn't prove that there are no other cluster points, since not all sequences in $A\setminus \{0\}$ are subsequences of $(a_n)$.

To prove that no other cluster points exist, you can use the definition. That is, show that given any other $x_0 \in \mathbb R$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$[(x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon)\cap A]\setminus \{x_0\} = \varnothing.$$
You can do this easily by splitting into cases:

1. $x_0 < 0$
2. $x_0 > 1$
3. $x_0 \in (0,1]\cap A$
4. $x_0 \in (0,1]\setminus A$

I'll prove one case for you, and by drawing pictures, you can figure out how to do the other three.

Suppose $x_0 > 1$. Let $\varepsilon = \frac{x_0-1}{2}$. Then $[(x_0 - \varepsilon, x_0 + \varepsilon)\cap A]\setminus \{x_0\} = \varnothing$, so $A$ has no cluster points greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a class, I think that $0$ being the limit of the sequence should suffice as an argument for $0$ being a cluster point of $A$ (if you discussed this in class yet). However I would suggest being more explicit in your proof that this is the only cluster point of the set $A$. Something like,

Suppose that $p \in \mathbb{R}$ is a cluster point of the set $A$. Then $\forall \epsilon >0$, the set $\{a_n \in A, |p-a_n|<\epsilon \}$ contains an infinite number of points. By the least upper bound property of $\mathbb{N}$, there is necessarily an index $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_i=\min \{a_n \in A, |p-a_n|<\epsilon \}$. You can continue this argument to show that the subsequence starting with $a_1,a_2,...,a_i$, and continuing with the points of $\{a_n \in A, |p-a_n|<\epsilon \}$, ordered by their indices, is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ with limit $p$. Then by the uniqueness of the limit of a sequence, $p=0$.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware, you can edit your answer instead of posting a new one. Just click "edit" below the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just made my first stack exchange account, I didnt realize anyone could see a deleted answer

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a flaw I've just realised. A subsequence of $a_n$ does not represent the entire set of subsequences **in** $A$. Hence I have not discovered what every subsequence in $A$ actually looks like.

Comment: For example the constant sequence $\frac{1}{2}$ and so on. It is not a direct subsequence of $a_n$ hence I have not considered it.

Comment: I'm just hoping for confirmation from some professionals, because as I said, I'm new to cluster points.